# Difference between TaskInstanceIAMRole and ECSExecutionRole in TaskDefinition Properties

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I see that, in TaskDefinition properties, one can define 2 kind of roles: ExecutionRoleArn and TaskRole Arn

I tried to understand from documentation about both:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition.html

But still I don’t understand the reasoning behind having two? Can someone explain why it is done so this way?

Answer (score 1):

**TaskRoleArn** refers to the arn of that role which will be utilized to call **other AWS services or access AWS resources** such as **permissions** needed for *writing data into DynamoDB table, read information from any S3 bucket, etc*.

**ExecutionRoleArn** refers to the arn of the role which will take care of ***permissions*** required for *publishing logs to CloudWatch as well as push and pull Docker images from Amazon ECR*.